# Checking if string is in the right format in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. Given a string, I'm trying to understand how to check if its in the right format. Each string should have the following format:

```
set ABC 1
set XYZ abc
```

Each string should start with `set` then contain two strings after it.
I know how to use regex to do it but I can't seem to understand which basic library should I use. I did some research but could not find the library which does what I need.

Comment: Is the question "How do I match a regex against a string in Java?"

Comment: You can use a Pattern object from the standard Java library: `Pattern.matches(String regex, String input);` which returns a boolean

Comment: 3rd should be of any length?

Comment: Could you provide an example? The second and third strings could be of any length with any characters.

Comment: @abuka123 So 2nd string could be of any size, not just three and with any characters, not just capital ones?

Comment: @abuka123 `Pattern.matches` uses regular expression syntax.  There are other java basic classes (i.e. not external libraries) that can be used to parse the string, such as StringTokenizer.  Note too that String has a lot of methods for manipulation of strings, but may not be obvious because they all work by returning a new string (no in-place changes; String objects are all immutable).

Answer (score 0):

what about a simple

```
str.startsWith("set") && str.split("\\s+").length == 3; // or >= 3
```